# How do you add dependencies to google dataflow?

Tags: java, opencv, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to add opencv to a data-flow project. And from what I have read, all you should have to do is add the opencv jar and it will be uploaded to the staging bucket. But I know that cant be all (mostly doesn't work). I get the following error when I try to run my code as a direct pipeline on my local machine.

---

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.VideoCapture_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.VideoCapture_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.<init>(VideoCapture.java:40)`

---

I have read this post,
[How do I add Java dependencies to a Google Dataflow project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465128/how-do-i-add-java-dependencies-to-a-google-dataflow-project) , but all it says it to add the jar to the classpath. Which doesnt work. I am missing something obvious I feel.

Comment: By "direct pipeline" you mean you are running the pipeline locally on your machine, using the in-memory runner? Can you confirm that this same class is accessible from your main() method? (if it's not, then the issue is in the way your program is being launched, rather than Dataflow)

Comment: I am running it locally, yes. But have also tried running on Google. And yes, it's reachable. The pipeline runs and even performs the first transform. But I get that error at the first opencv call

Answer (score 1):

UnsatisfiedLinkError is:
Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html

Since the issue is occurring when you build/run locally, it is not related to the Dataflow Service or uploading to a staging bucket.

A quick Google search for "opencv UnsatisfiedLinkError" brought up many results.  The most common response was that this line is missing:

```
static {
  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```